# Check appearance of UI design in Qt Creator

Tags: forms, qt, qt-creator

I am experimenting with Qt Creator to design a main window form. Works like a charm. However from time to time I would like to check the visual appearance and the layout resize behaviour of the form. And I would like to do this without starting the entire application.

Is there a way to quickly render/visualize/open the designed form to check how it will behave and look like (without the business logic of course)? Probably I missed something obvious...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Tools > Form Editor > Preview...`:

[image: qt creator screenshot]